# What causes this fatal error in the Amazon Corretto JVM?

Tags: memory-leaks, jvm, corretto

When running my application on the Amazon Corretto JVM I encountered the following error. What does this mean?

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fcde9765caa, pid=1, tid=144
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.18.10.1 (11.0.18+10) (build 11.0.18+10-LTS)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.18.10.1 (11.0.18+10-LTS, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0xc03caa]  ObjectSampleCheckpoint::add_to_leakp_set(Method const*, unsigned long)+0x7a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reporting a JVM crash, always include `hs_err.log` dump produced by the JVM. A short error message is not enough to provide a definitive conclusion.

In your case, however, the reason is most likely the JVM bug [JDK-8236743](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8236743).

Upgrade to JDK 17+ where the issue is already fixed or disable `OldObjectSample` events in your JFR recording.

Comment: how do i disable `OldObjectSample` events? are they enabled by default?

Comment: and what leads you to believe that disabling that would solve the SIGSEGV issue?

Comment: @Jewels This depends on how you start JFR. See [Configure Events and Flight Recorder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/jfapi/configuration.html)